# Firebase ChildEventListener is being called with a delay

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a ChildEventListener to a node, the problem I'm facing is when a new message is added to the node and the app is open I get the onChildAdded callback. But when the app is killed and a message is added to the room, on opening the app onChildAdded gives all the node data, but there's a delay in getting the last data item in the list.

I'm using `firebase-client-android:2.3.1`

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, that's the expected behavior from the `onChildAdded` callback. At first, *all* currently defined child nodes are returned; afterwards only newly added nodes are returned.

Not clear if your delay is resulting from having many child nodes *already* defined when your app starts. Or maybe all previous child nodes have been already been *locally cached*, explaining the fast result you are getting.

Comment: Since firebase has all the list items under the node, when app is opened onChildAdded gives me everything I need, but the last item in the list comes with a delay. The question is how all the items in the list are retrieved quickly but not the last item.

Comment: Has setPersisitanceEnable got to do something with this?

Comment: @VeereshCharantimath Yes, it might! All but the last could have been locally cached already, explaining the fast performance.

Comment: Is there any workaround to this, because I have used firebase 10.6.0 which did not have this issue. But I'm working on a legacy project which uses firebase-client-android:2.3.1

Comment: @VeereshCharantimath Probably your best bet is to upgrade Firebase, if possible at all :-(